# Sending post data from swift datatask to PHP fails due to data corruption. How to fix this?

Tags: php, swift, post, struct

I send a POST request in my Swift app to my server, but the data received by the server is different from what I intended to send to the server.

The data I try to send is:

```
let parameters = PostData(
  previousVisit : previousVisit,
  lang : lang,
  object : object,
  enrolledSince : since
)
```

Which comes down in practice to:

```
PostData(previousVisit: "2024-03-20T10:33:48", lang: "NL", object: "{\"Location\":[\"19\"],\"Event\":[]}", enrolledSince: "{}")
```

But the server receives:

```
array(1) {
  ["{"lang":"NL","object":"{\"Location\":"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["\"19\""]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

This is really strange. It seems that a part of the data is interpreted as key and a part as value and some data is lost.

This is the code I use to send it:

```
let url = URL(string: "MyPHPServer.com/script.php")!
let session = URLSession.shared
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
```

etc.

Where did I fail?

I expect the same result on the server as in Swift. I tried to find out why it fails, by I couldn't find it.

Comment: _"But the server receives:"_ - received _how_? What exactly is it that you dumped there?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue including how you defined the data in the Swift code originally, and how you are reading and logging those two data samples. Aside from what's apparently missing, there also seems to be a bit of a mess where you've got double-encoded JSON (which suggests you've placed an existing JSON string inside an object that you then JSON-encode...that doesn't usually make a lot of sense).

Comment: You need to specify the "Content-Type" header of your post request. Presumably, it's `application/json`. If you omit this header, a server should not process the body in any way. Instead, it should return a "Bad Request".

Comment: `a server should not process the body in any way`...or it might just try to process it as some other content type. Depends how the server is configured, and also how the code which receives the request tries to process the data. e.g. in PHP, reading JSON froma request body, and reading form-url-encoded data needs to be done via different code. I agree though it would certainly help the server to understand the request if that header is included.

Comment: @CBroe, i dumpt the $_POST variable with var_dump($_POST)

Comment: @ADyson: The first code-block tells you the structure of struct PostData I want to send. The values are all Strings. The second code-block is the print in XCode console of the instantiated struct, so you can see what I like to send. In other languages you can send: previousVisit=String&lang=String&... etc. that is wat I would expect. I have a good reason to store 2 jsonstrings in this struct.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I tried your suggestion. Then I receive an empy $_POST variable on the server.

Comment: The problem is that your request body contains JSON, but the request's `Content-Type` header apparently still is either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` (otherwise PHP would not even attempt to populate $_POST to begin with.) You either need to send the data in a format that matches the specified content type, or you need to use the common method to make PHP actually read & parse a JSON request body.

Comment: `I have a good reason to store 2 jsonstrings in this struct`...really? Why not just keep everything in a data structure in Swift and then encode _all_ of it, once, so you have a single coherent JSON object to decode at the other end? Then you don't have to worry about decoding twice.

Comment: @ADyson, I receive both values from a message handler already in JSONstring format. So an extra decode and encode is omitted in this way.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem or a Swift problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase, it was a Swift problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't understand it, but I found a working solution.

```
let queryItems = [
  URLQueryItem(name: "previousVisit", value: previousVisit),
  URLQueryItem(name: "lang", value: lang),
  URLQueryItem(name: "object", value: object),
  URLQueryItem(name: "enrolledSince", value: since)
]

// Create a URLComponents object using blank url
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "")
        
// Assign the query items to the object
urlComponents?.queryItems = queryItems
        
// Fetch the formatted string from the URLComponents object
let request_body = urlComponents!.query!
    
request.setValue(
 "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type"
)
 
request.httpMethod = "POST"
                       
request.httpBody = Data(request_body.utf8)
```

This worked in the `session.DataTask` for me.

Comment: What bit of this don't you understand? Perhaps we can clarify it for you. You're now sending this as form-url-encoded data instead of JSON. PHP will then happily read that into the $_POST variables correctly, as it's pre-configured to do. It can't do that with JSON data. If you send JSON from your app (like you were doing originally), you'd need to follow the instructions in guides such as [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php) so that PHP would read it correctly.